# Team access for remotely shared GeoPackage

Tags: software-recommendations, geopackage

I am looking for ways where an annotator using GeoPackage Layer can save the gpkg database somewhere that can be accessed by a supervisor/QA person for checking and corrections, save edits, and then the annotator re-checks his/her work again and create changes on the same gpkg file that was previously edited by the QA person.

The archaic way to do this is to simply share the gpkg file all over again from the annotator to the QA and back to the annotator.

Is there a way to do this remotely, perhap using a cloud storage like GDrive?

Answer (score -1):

I would implement a simple audit history mechanism, one which captures

- Author
- Date edited
- Changes from/to.
- Whether it was an Insert/update/delete.

Then provide the QA/Supervisor with a view of the data.
ie: A simple layer file, which stylizes, or filters the data, based on edits in the last date, or however you like.

Then have another field called 'QA_approved' and have a simple mechanism which allows the the QA person to approve the changes, make modifications etc.

'Master views' would filter out any data currently 'under review' as such.

In other words, at a high level, implement a solution using fields, status and filters/layers.

That would be a good starting point. Then you can jazz it up later with GUI's, or automated workflows or tasks lists. Automatic field population (dates/status/usernames) and - id aim for the audit_history details to be a relational table in your database. (or maybe even a seperate database, depending upon how big your data is and how many changes are made).

Comment: I am not really particular on those things whether the QA is already done or what not or the audit trail. I am more particular how to seamlessly share GPKGs with the team where one person can edit a gpkg file and the QA person can access the same edited file for checking

Comment: multi-edit is possible, if you separate the tables out. Hence the suggestion to have audit_table separate. ie: the solution lies in having the QA editing a different table to the main editor.

Comment: yes, but it doesnt tell me which tools to use at all

Comment: The answer i gave is a 'database design' answer - not a 'download this plugin/use this tool' answer.... If you need help doing database design, have a go first, read some doco and when you get stuck you can come back and ask a more specific question when you get stuck.